# Multiple Dynamic Queries in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to execute about `100 Update / Delete` Dynamic Queries made with PHP and sent to MySQL Stored Procedure.

Currently I can execute single Dynamic Query in Stored Procedure with this code like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateBill`(IN `queryIs` VARCHAR(10000))
BEGIN
    SET @t1 = queryIs;
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
    EXECUTE stmt3;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
END
```

But this can execute only single query terminated with `;`. But I have about 100 Dynamic Queries and want to execute them like

```
update abc set a=1, b=0 where c=5;
update abc set a=7, b=3 where c=6;
delete from abc where c = 3;
update abc set a=9, b=2 where c=8;
update abc set a=2, b=1 where c=12;
delete from abc where c = 10;
```

All of above queries are PHP made data sent from client data. I don't want to rapidly create connection with server and execute above queries one by one but I just want to send above queries as on single string in stored procedure parameter and then create dynamic queries from it and then execute all of above.

Comment: You can of course just split the parameter at e.g. `;` (or add a second parameter that contain the lengths, it will make it easier to distinguish between a string containing a `';'` and the actual delimiter) and execute them in a loop. On the other hand, there is absolutely no reason to do so. Just open a connection and execute the queries one by one (or prepared) from php. It is actually faster than using dynamic sql, can do more and otherwise will do exactly the same thing. (That is what an api is for. If you could optimize it by doing it your way, it would have been implemented already).

Comment: And also you could use a multiquery in php if you absolutely want to send it at once, so one query call with your whole string, not via the stored procedure. It is not faster, but might make it easier for you (I'm not exactly sure what the reason behind your idea is).

Answer (score 0):

It was not really 100% clear to me what your intention is
but it seems that you have to do String processing in your procedure which is a lot of work if you want to predict every possible case.